# Property setters and getters missing in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, swift, getter-setter

I'm trying to convert [this](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/10/custom-colored-disclosure-indicators/) Objective-C class to Swift.

Below is what I'm done so far.

```
import UIKit

public class CustomColoredAccessory: UIControl {

    var accessoryColor = UIColor()
    var highlightedColor = UIColor()

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override public func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let x: CGFloat = CGRectGetMaxX(bounds) - 3
        let y: CGFloat = CGRectGetMaxY(bounds)
        let R: CGFloat = 4.5

        let ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctxt, x - R, y - R)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, x, y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, x - R, y + R)
        CGContextSetLineCap(ctxt, kCGLineCapSquare)
        CGContextSetLineJoin(ctxt, kCGLineJoinMiter)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctxt, 3)

        if highlighted == true {
            highlightedColor.setStroke()
        } else {
            accessoryColor.setStroke()
        }
        CGContextStrokePath(ctxt)
    }

    public class func accessoryWithColor(color: UIColor) -> CustomColoredAccessory {
        var ret = CustomColoredAccessory(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 11, 15))
        ret.accessoryColor = color

        return ret
    }
}
```

In the origin Objective-C code, there's one setter and two getters for the two properties.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {

    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (UIColor *)accessoryColor {
    if (!_accessoryColor) {
        return [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return _accessoryColor;
}

- (UIColor *)highlightedColor {
    if (!_highlightedColor) {
        return [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return _highlightedColor;
}
```

I noticed that property setters and getters are gone i Swift. At least a little different.

I tried adding the setter to `highlightedColor` like this,

```
var highlightedColor = UIColor() {
    set {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

But I get this error at the `set` line - **Use of unresolved identifier 'set'**

Can someone please tell me how to correct this error? I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The setter and getter are both placed in the variable declaration:

```
var highlightedColor: UIColor {
    set {
        //custom setter
    }
    get {
        //custom getter
    }
}
```

You would also need to include the `get`. Anyway, if you want to call `setNeedsDisplay()` you would be better off by using a "property observer" like so:

```
var highlightedColor: UIColor {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

For more info take a look at [Swift Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)